# How to fix "object of type 'int' has no len()" in Python3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to Python programming. I'm trying to connect to MySQL from Python. My goal is to retrieve the `rows` from a `table` when user click on a "View" `button` on the gui and display them on a `listbox` which I designed using the Page gui builder for Python. I put the database connection codes in the **init** function of the generated Tkinter file, and created a function `showdetails(self)` to handle the retrieving of the rows from the table. I'm sure the connection to the database works. However, when I run it I get `object of type 'int' has no len()` `error`. I really don't know what could be responsible. I need help please.

I have tried to write the code in a different file from the Tkinter file with few modification, and it works perfectly. The rows in the specified table were retrieved in the console

## Some lines of my codes

```
import pymysql.cursors

def showdetails(self):

    try:
        with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `students`")
            for i in range(0, len(sql)):
                self.listBox.insert(i, sql.rows[i])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def __init__(self, top=None):
    # connect to database
    try:
      self.conn = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'victor16', 'students', charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    except Exception as e:
      print(e, ': could not connect to database')
```

I want the `listbox` to display the `rows` from the database, but it's not.

Comment: When you execute a query using `cursor.execute()`, this returns nothing; to get the result of the query you would do `cursor.fetchall()` (or fetchone), store it in a variable and then iterate over the length of the the variable which will be a tuple/list.

Comment: without `multi=True` `cursor.execute` returns a value not an iterable. And `len` doesn"t work on iterables unless you convert to `list` first

Comment: Thanks Ernxst for your help. I used the cursor.fetchall() function and it worked. However, the result was returned in descending order, that row 2 comes before row1. Also the curly braces { } is still around the fields. Is there a way i can remove that?

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'sql' is capturing the record count of the SQL query, so you don't need to use the 'len' function.

Alternatively you could use len(sql.rows) in your loop!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I followed the instruction by @Ernxst by using fetchall(), and that fixed the problem